# Nacks vs error handlers defined on listenerFactory

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My KafkaConsumer is currently configured to have auto-commit to false. With that I am leveraging Acknowledgement to commit the offset; where I have a call to acknowledge when the event is successful and when nack on any exceptions occuring.
My understanding of nacks is that it provides a means of retrying the event that had errored out by retriggering the poll with the proper offsets.

In addition to that, I had defined a CommonErrorHandler thats configured against my ListenerFactory; and so I am curious if this error handler is needed.
If so what use-cases would leverage the error handler defined?